# Blender's solid-mode and material-preview-mode don't look the same

Tags: 3d-view, draw-mode

Left model is in material-preview-mode, right model is in solid-mode:

[image]

My main problem is that I can't get my chess texture to appear on the material so that it looks the same in solid-mode and material-preview-mode. I am a total beginner in Blender. Do I need to change anything regarding UV mapping? Why does the texture change so much while in the material-preview-mode?

Answer (score 3):

I assume that you are talking about using the *Texture* color mode in the Solid viewport shading settings:

[image]

This mode is not very sophisticated. It works like this:

- If you have an *active* image texture node in your object’s material, the viewport will use it for shading.
- The texture is mapped using the active UV map for the object.
- All other aspects of the material are **ignored**.

This means that if you use nodes to combine information from multiple textures or to alter the texture mapping in any way, those details will *not* be reflected in Solid mode. This makes the *Texture* color mode not particularly useful for all but the simplest of materials.

Generally, I recommend not bothering with textured display in Solid mode. Just use the Material Preview mode to get a textured preview of your model. That’s what it’s there for.

Comment: The problem is that the texture should look like it is shown in solid viewport shading. I use the texture color mode that you mention. I just wanted to know why the texture changes completely when I switch to material-preview-mode.

Comment: @DominikRifert It is impossible to know what could be causing your texture mapping issues without seeing the material settings you are using for that object. Consider [asking a new question](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/ask) about the texture mapping issues specifically, and include screenshots of both the material nodes and your UV map. You can also consider uploading your .blend file to https://pasteall.org/blend/ to make it easier for people to debug.

Answer (score -1):

If you wish to have a shadeless view of textures.

Use the `material preview` view instead of the `rendered` view.

To my understanding, there is no way for textures to show-up while in `solid` view.

[image]

Comment: This is not true—you can use the *Texture* color mode to get limited textured shading in Solid mode, as I explain in my answer.

Comment: You're absolutely right! The author said "textures" and I was thinking about it in technical, image terms, not color terms.